# opengl glut stopped working

Tags: eclipse, opengl, glut

I'm trying to launch hello world program using opengl and glut(eclipse). I always get message Program.exe has stopped working. I'm using windows.
I installed MinGW.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif


void displayCall() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 500.0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(2, 2, 2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glScalef(.005,.005,.005);
  glRotatef(20, 0, 1, 0);
  glRotatef(30, 0, 0, 1);
  glRotatef(5, 1, 0, 0);
  glTranslatef(-300, 0, 0);

  glColor3f(1,1,1);
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'H');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'e');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'l');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'l');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'o');

  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'W');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'o');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'r');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'l');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, 'd');
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, '!');

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
  glutInitWindowPosition(300, 200);
  glutCreateWindow("Hello World!");
  glutDisplayFunc(displayCall);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

I copy glut32.dll in C:\Windows\System32 folder,  glut.h in the folder C:\MinGW\include\GL and libglut32.a in C:\MinGW\lib.
I set in eclipse project->properties->c/c++ Build->Settings->MinGw c++ Linker->Libraries(add): glut32,glu32,opengl32. I don't know why it crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles just fine.  It also executes OK so its not a coding issue, just a library setup issue.  On linux with necessary libraries installed I compiled your code using

```
gcc -o hello_world_glut hello_world_glut.c -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

assure you are looking at the console window in Eclipse for errors

Comment: I'm using windows. I have no errors/warnings in console.

Comment: I do not use Windows, however its probably best to not copy DLL files into OS (operating system) directories ... instead you tell eclipse the path to reach your API libraries then list out needed libraries ... eclipse right click on your project then Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries ... then Add each library as in  GL   glut   GLU   .... then tab  Includes to add where your header .h  files live